# Notice: Undefined index: hits

Tags: php, elasticsearch

i have an search query and after executing the search  query i put the $result into an array.

**My PHP Code -**

```
$contents = $client->search($params); // executing the search

$search = array($contents); // make the result $contents as a array
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($search); $i++) {
$search['hits']['total']['title'] = strip_tags($search['hits']['total']['title']); // Trying to access the title
```

**results in a array ----**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [took] => 1 
        [timed_out] => 
        [_shards] => Array ( 
            [total] => 2 
            [successful] => 2 
            [failed] => 0 
        ) 
        [hits] => Array (     
            [total] => 1 
            [max_score] => 2.6818755 
            [hits] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [_index] => myindex 
                    [_type] => mytype 
                    [_id] => p36d3742b982586d8d 
                    [_score] => 2.6818755 
                    [_source] => Array ( 
                        [title] => Salma Hayek  => Salma Hayeks... 
                        [source] => Hello 
                        [guid] => p36d3742b982586d8d 
                        [pub_id] => 54ae51e5 
                        [type] => news
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Now the problem is every time i try to access the title it says Notice: **Undefined index: hits**.

i have tried like ---

```
$search['hits']['total']['title'] = strip_tags($search['hits']['total']['title']);

$search['']['hits']['total']['title'] = strip_tags($search['']['hits']['total']['title']);
```

Nothing is working for me, may be  am making a simple mistake, anyone knows where i am making the mistake.

i have also tried to use it like so ----

```
$search[$i]['hits']['total']['title'] = strip_tags($search[$i]['hits']['total']['title']);
```

But it return me an error like:

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

How can I access my title?

Comment: if you dump your array in a readable way you would more easily find the correct route to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `$i`, use `$search[$i]['hits']`.

This is where title is `$search[$i]['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['title']`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if i do so it return me "Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array " !

Comment: use $search[$i]['hits']['total'] is not an array, it is an integer.

Comment: i knows it's an integer but it is returning me that error

Comment: Since $search[$i]['hits']['total'] is an integer and not an array you cannot use $search[$i]['hits']['total']['title'] which thinks $search[$i]['hits']['total'] is an array.

Comment: So how i can get the title, do u have any suggestion please :)

Comment: This is where the title is: $search[$i]['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['title']

Comment: You need to probably loop through $search[$i]['hits']['hits'] since it is an array